# sqlite android select sum

Tags: android, sqlite, sum

my table look like this:

```
Client_Code    Oder_ID  NoOrd   Weight
850458         5        1       12
850458         5        2       12
850458         6        1        5
```

i want to sum the Weight, but unique par Oder_ID.
so the resultat that i want is 17 = 12 + 5
not 29

how can i do that ?

my code like this;

```
public int GetPoids()
    {           
        String SQL_syntax = "SELECT SUM("+ DBHelper.KEY_Poids +") as SumPoids FROM " +  DBHelper.tableName + " GROUP BY " + DBHelper.KEY_CodeClient +","+DBHelper.KEY_NoOrdre ;
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(SQL_syntax, null);

         if (c != null)
                c.moveToFirst();

        int Poids = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();       

        return Poids;        
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: are you sure about the table's content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Give a try**, 
First you need to get unique OrderIds then take only one record of that OrderId with one more condition `NoOrd=1` (it **must** have atleast NoOrd=1 in each record)

```
select sum(Weight) from Table_Name where Order_ID in (select distinct Order_ID from Table_Name) and NoOrd=1
```

Sorry if it doesn't help you, actually I tried on a online tool due to lack of your database structure.